# How to specify specific version of Firebase Analytics a pod file should use

Tags: ios, cocoapods

If I update my pod file to the latest versions then the app stops compiling, the Firebase pods have some internal compilation error and I don't have the time right now to figure out what the problem is in somebody else's component.
However if I try and specify what version of Firebase/Analytics its saying there isn't such a version.

```
- Firebase 6.11.0 -> (unused) (latest version 6.16.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics 6.1.3 -> 6.2.2 (latest version 6.2.2)
- FirebaseCore 6.3.2 -> 6.6.1 (latest version 6.6.1)
- FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 1.1.1 -> 1.2.0 (latest version 1.2.0)
- FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop 1.0.0 -> 1.2.0 (latest version 1.2.0)
- FirebaseInstanceID 4.2.6 -> 4.3.0 (latest version 4.3.0)
- GoogleAppMeasurement 6.1.3 -> 6.2.2 (latest version 6.2.2)
- GoogleDataTransport 3.0.1 -> 3.3.1 (latest version 3.3.1)
- GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport 1.2.1 -> 1.3.1 (latest version 1.3.1)
- GoogleUtilities 6.3.1 -> (unused) (latest version 6.5.1)
```

I'm not specifying all those in the pod file, I only specify Firebase/Analytics, all the other must be dependencies of Firebase/Analytics.
It says the FirebaseAnalytics version currently installed is 6.1.3, yet if I add this to my podfile as so:

```
...
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.1.3'
...
```

Then run pod update, this is the result:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 6.1.3)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 6.1.3)`.
```

So therefore what version should I specify in the pod file so that Firebase/Analytics isn't updated?

Answer (score 7):

Use `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '6.1.3'` without the slash.

`Firebase/Analytics` indicates the [Analytics subspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json#L59) of the Firebase pod.
`FirebaseAnalytics` is the [FirebaseAnalytics pod](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.2.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json).

Comment: Can you explain whats a difference please?

Comment: See the CocoaPods docs(https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)  for an explanation of subspecs.  The two syntaxes continue to be functionally the same for `FirebaseAnalytics`, but the `Firebase/Analytics` subspec may go away at some point in the future.